# Dropdown scroll issue when we move out and scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I have a dropdown(kendo Dropdown) with some data. when i scroll inside the dropdown means it's working properly.

When i open the dropdown and i move the mouse out and then i scroll means the dropdown data part also moved .

Image Attached check the image.

Dropdown code:(Dropdown is inside the  section)

```
<input id="category" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: $root.CategoryList, dataTextField: 'ServiceCategoryName', dataValueField: 'ServiceCategoryID', change:$root.CategorySelect,value:ServiceCategoryID }">
```

---

How can i close the dropdown when i scroll outside ???[image]

Comment: If you check the Kendo UI demo this is "expected bahaviour": http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index You should file an issue with them.

Comment: Ya this issue already exists in kendo too... for now i fixed this issue using window scroll funtion in jqery...

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it:

```
$("body").scroll(function(){
    if(!$("#category").hover()){
        $("#category").hide();
    }
});
```

Not sure how to close the dropdown but you get the idea.